# About CHAR default value when set to NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a sql script and run it using navicat, while when I delete the **DEFAULT 32**, it works well. Why? Thank you.

*My Dev Env:
MySQL 5.7 installed on win11.*

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
   `student_id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 12,
   `studeng_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 4,
   `password` CHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT 32,
   PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
)
> 1067 - Invalid default value for 'password'
> Time: 0.001s
```

Comment: And I tried to change password field to DEFAULT 16, it doesn't work too. Opps.

Comment: Why are you using a number as the default value instead of a string?

Comment: A 1-character password is not very secure.

Comment: I miss understand the lenght and the default value. Actually I want the set the passwword as CHAR(32);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CHAR` is equivalent to `CHAR(1)`. When `32` is converted to the string `'32'`, it doesn't fit in a 1-character string.

It looks like you're trying to specify the default using the ASCII code of the character. That's not how numbers are converted to strings. Getting a string from an ASCII code requires calling the `CHAR()` function, but you can't call functions in the `DEFAULT` clause (with a few exceptions like `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`).

So you need to write the default as a string.

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
   `student_id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 12,
   `student_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\d',
   `password` CHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
   PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
)
```

Comment: I am new to DataBase Desgin tool ( I am test the dynobird.com) .and there is no any LENGTH input field for the table. I miss understand the LENGTH and DEFAULT VALUE. <BR>And it still worked to import the DEFAULT Value to LENGTH VALUE when I using the SQL file that from the dbatabase website. Actually My CHAR should be CHAR(32) and the DEFAULT should using what you input. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You probably want `VARCHAR` rather than `CHAR`.